# Consulta sobre react router. Donde debe ir el BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

tengo una duda sobre react router al usarlo en un proyecto. Donde iria el BrowserRouter que va a contener las Routes? en el index.js o en app.js? Vi 2 proyectos donde lo usaban y en uno lo ponian en el index y en otro en app. Espero que puedan aclararme esa duda, muchas gracias!

El que vi en que lo usaban en el index.js era algo asi:

```
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="items/:id" element={<Detail />} />
            <Route path="Cart/" element={<CartViews />} />
            <Route path="tipo/:nombreCategoria" element={<Categorias />}/>
            <Route path="Contacto/" element={<Contacto imagen="redes" />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En resumen `react-router-dom` proporciona múltiples enrutadores entre los cuales figura el motivo de tu pregunta `<BrowserRouter>`

Básicamente si queremos proporcionar rutas dentro de toda nuestra aplicación, debemos envolver todo nuestro árbol de componentes con `<BrowserRouter>`.

`<BrowserRouter>` tiene la función principal poder declarar rutas individuales dentro de nuestra aplicación.

---

En cuanto a tu duda de **donde declararlo:** Esto va a depender de la estructura de tu aplicación, no afecta donde lo utilices ya que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
// index.js
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))

// App.js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

o lo siguiente:

```
// App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" component={SampleComponent} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

// index.js
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Claro siempre va a depender de la estructura que le de a mi aplicacion. muchas gracias por solucionar mi duda!!